# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result столбец с названием read

Tags: php, mysqli, header

В коде выдаёт ошибку:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\sitedota\module\news\material.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\sitedota\module\news\material.php:6) in C:\OpenServer\domains\sitedota\index.php on line 91

https://gist.github.com/Orange-Men/d0dab7e34116def6febe

скрин таблицы https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4TGL.jpg

Вот код:
**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'setting.php';
session_start();
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$CONNECT = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

if ($_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] != 1 and $_COOKIE['user']) {
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT id, name, regdate, email, country, avatar, login FROM users WHERE password = '$_COOKIE[user]'"));
    $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'] = $Row['login'];
    $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = $Row['id'];
    $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $Row['name'];
    $_SESSION['USER_REGDATE'] = $Row['regdate'];
    $_SESSION['USER_EMAIL'] = $Row['email'];
    $_SESSION['USER_COUNTRY'] = UserCountry($Row['country']);
    $_SESSION['USER_AVATAR'] = $Row['avatar'];
    $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] = 1;
}
// Единая точка входа
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){
    $Page = 'index';
    $Module = 'index';
}else{
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);

    if (!empty($Module)){
        $Param = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++){
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}
//Наши страницы
if ($Page == 'index' and $Module == 'index') include('page/index.php');
else if ($Page == 'login') include('page/login.php');
else if ($Page == 'register') include('page/register.php');
else if ($Page == 'account') include('form/account.php');
else if ($Page == 'profile') include('page/profile.php');
else if ($Page == 'restore') include('page/restore.php');
else if ($Page == 'guestbook') include('page/guestbook.php');

else if ($Page == 'news'){
    if (!$Module or $Page == 'news' and $Module == 'category' or $Page == 'news' and $Module == 'main')
        include('module/news/main.php');
    else if ($Module == 'material')
        include('module/news/material.php');
}
//Проверка на авторизацию
function ULogin($p1) {
    if ($p1 <= 0 and $_SESSION[USER_LOGIN_IN] != $p1)
        MessageSend(1, 'Данная страница доступна только для гостей.', '/');
    else if ($_SESSION[USER_LOGIN_IN] != $p1)
        MessageSend(1, 'Данная страница доступна только для пользователей сайта.', '/');
}
//Страны
function UserCountry($p1) {
    if ($p1 == 1)
        return 'Украина';
    if ($p1 == 2)
        return 'Россия';
    if ($p1 == 3)
        return 'Беларусь';
    if ($p1 == 4)
        return 'Казахстан';
}
//Рандомная строка
function RandomString($p1) {
    $Char = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $String = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $p1; $i ++)
        $String .= $Char[rand(0, strlen($Char) - 1)];
    return $String;
}
//Скрыте символов в email после @
function HideEmail($p1) {
    $Explode = explode('@', $p1);
    return $Explode[0].'@*****';
}
//Выплывающее сообщение об ошибке, подсказке или информации.
function MessageSend($p1, $p2, $p3 = '') {
    if ($p1 == 1)
        $p1 = 'Ошибка';
    else if ($p1 == 2)
        $p1 = 'Подсказка';
    else if ($p1 == 3)
        $p1 = 'Информация';
    $_SESSION['message'] = '<div class = MessageBlock><b>'.$p1.'</b>: '.$p2.'</div>';
    if ($p3)
        $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = $p3;
    exit(header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
}
//Вывод этой ошибки, подсказки или информации.
function MessageShow(){
    if ($_SESSION['message'])
        $Message = $_SESSION['message'];
        echo $Message;
    $_SESSION['message'] = array();
}
//Проверка
//nl2br — Вставляет HTML-код разрыва строки перед каждым переводом строки
//htmlspecialchars — Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности
//trim — Удаляет пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки
function FormChars ($p1) {
    return nl2br(htmlspecialchars(trim($p1), ENT_QUOTES), false);
}
//Шифровка md5
function GenPass ($p1, $p2){
    return md5('Orange_Men'.md5('123'.$p1.'321').md5('456'.$p2.'654'));
}
//<head>
function Head($p1) {
    echo "
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>$p1</title>
    <meta name='keywords' content='' />
    <meta name='description' content='' />
    <link href='/resource/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>";
}
//Функция переключателя страниц
//$p1 - URL (Example: /news/main/page)
//$p2 - Текущая страница ($Param['page'])
//$p3 - Кол-во новостей
//$p4 - Кол-во новостей на странице
function PageSelector($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4 = 5) {
    $Page = $p3[0] / $p4; // делим кол-во новостей на кол-во записей на странице
    if ($Page > 1) { //А нужен ли переключатель ?
        echo '<div class = "PageSelector">';
        for ($i = ($p2 - 3); $i < ($Page + 1); $i++) {
            if ($i > 0 and $i <= ($p2 + 3)) {
                if ($p2 == $i)
                    $Swch = 'SwchItemCur';
                else $Swch = 'SwchItem';
                echo '<a class = "page_selector_a '.$Swch.'" href = "'.$p1.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
//MenuHead
function Menu() {
    if ($_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] != 1)
        $Menu = "<a href = '/register'><div class = 'Menu'>Регистрация</div></a>
                 <a href = '/login'><div class = 'Menu'>Вход</div></a>";
    else $Menu = "<a href = '/profile'><div class = 'Menu'>Профиль</div></a>
                  <a href = '/guestbook'><div class = 'Menu'>Гостевая книга</div></a>";

    echo "<div class = 'MenuHead'>
            <a href = '/'><div class = 'Menu'>Главная</div></a>
            <a href = '/news'><div class = 'Menu'>Новости</div></a>
            $Menu
        </div>";
}
//<footer>
function Footer() {
    echo "<footer class='footer'>
            Orange_Men<br> Все права защищены
          </footer>";
}
?>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>
```

**material.php**

```
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT name, cat, readed, added, text, date FROM news WHERE id = '.$Param['id']));
if (!$Row['name'])
    MessageSend(1, 'Произошла ошибка, обратитесь к администратору.', '/news');
mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'UPDATE news SET readed = readed + 1 WHERE id = '.$Param['id']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php Head($Row['name']);?>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php Menu();
        MessageShow();
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php Footer() ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

update3:

в таблице (БД) изменил столбец 'read' на 'readed'. Всё, ошибок нет. Кто подскажет почему SQL так реагирует ?

Comment: @Вадим, данным из массива `$_COOKIE` доверять нельзя.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо, в будущем учту, но главный вопрос не об этом. Или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @Вадим, и по ссылке в первом комментарии к вопросу и в ответе ниже написано: предыдущий запрос относительно mysqli_fetch_assoc к базе вернул ошибку, отсюда 1 ваш Warning. Второй ваш Warning говорит о том, что вы отсылаете заголовок, но содержимое страницы уже было отправлено пользователю. Это происходит либо из-за вывода текста первого Warning, либо у вас не правильно построена логика скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ошибкам:

1. Какая-то операция в MySQL была выполнена с ошибкой(false), и вы это не проверили.
2. Вы отправляете заголовки уже после того, как отправили саму страницу - так делать нельзя, однако именно это происходит в MessageSend.
3. `text`, `date`, `read`, `name` - [зарезервированные ключевые слова](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html), и использовать их в запросах просто так нельзя. Обрамите его символом обратной черточки:

   ```
   SELECT `name`, `added`, `date`, `read`, `text` FROM news WHERE id = '.$Param['id']
   ```

   А ещё лучше - перейдите на использование ORM, вместо ручного построения запросов.

Comment: страницу не отправили - она сама отправилась, т.к. включен вывод ошибок в браузер

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov Я знаю что mysqli_connect вернул false, по этому я и обратился сюда что бы кто то ткнул мне носом.

Comment: @Вадим, в что ткнули? Если `mysqli_connect` вернул false, то смотрите в текст `mysqli::$error`, да решайте проблему которая там описывается.

Comment: @Вадим, дополнил ответом на третье сообщение об ошибке

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, тогда уж имена всех полей и таблиц в апострофы ;)

Comment: Изменил запрос по вашему примеру, ничего не изменилось. Вопрос обновил

Comment: @Вадим, что не изменилось? Какая ошибка выдаётся сейчас?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov изменил имя столбца с read на readed, так как вы были правы, read это зарезервированое имя. Спасибо вам.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

false также может возвращаться, если по запросу ничего не найдено в БД, проверьте `$Param['id']`, есть ли такой в вашей БД. Если решится первая проблема, возможно, вторая решится сама собой.

Comment: Увы в базе всё нормально, там 15 id-шников.

Comment: id-шников может быть много, но в `$Param['id']` может приходить не совсем то, что ожидается. Если вы уверены, что в базе есть id=1, попробуйте в запросе вместо `$Param['id']` поставить 1. Если запрос выполнится, то проблема в `$Param['id']`, если нет, то пробуйте `$CONNECT = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);` завернуть в try catch и ловите ошибку соединения

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Не могу понять, почему на read ругается. Может нет такого поля в базе? Попробуйте вместо имен полей написать *, если сработает запрос, тогда дело в именах

Comment: Я для работы с sqlite пользуюсь [плагином](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) но он только для mozilla Очень удобно, как phpMyAdmin

Comment: Я тоже им пользуюсь) Он встроен в OpenServer. Я поставил * в запросе, и всё работает...

Comment: В таком случае, попробуйте свой запрос в этом плагине исполнить, может там поподробнее будет написано, что это за ошибка. Мне трудно ответить, не видя таблицы.

Comment: скрин таблицы https://imgur.com/sziSjsQ